# Attempted to access nv(2.8); index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matlab

I'm very new to MatLab and I am trying to write a simple flash calculation code, however I am getting the above error. I was wondering if you could help me. I'm not sure what the error is asking.

```
Zi = [0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]; 
pvi = [190, 72.2 51.6, 20.44, 15.57, 4.956]; 
Ki = [3.8, 1.444, 1.032, 0.4088, 0.3114, 0.09912];
A = 0;
B = 0;
for i = 1:length(Zi)
  A = A + Zi(i)*(Ki(i)-1);
B = B + Zi(i)*((1/Ki(i))-1);
  end
nv0= A/(A+B);
% Display an error message if 0<nv<1
if nv0 > 1 || nv0 < 0 || nv0 ==0
  error('nv guess is incorrect')
end
% Step 2 - Solving Equation 5 - 16 for nv Using Newton-Raphson Method
nv = nv0;
nv0 = nv + .01; % Is this for the first gues abs dev?
itermax = 200;
fnkd = 0;
fnk = 0;
while abs(nv0 - nv) > tol & iter < itermax
  iter = iter + 1;
  nv0 = nv;
for i= 1:length(Zi)
      fnk = fnk + ((Zi(i) * (Ki(i)-1))/(nv(Ki(i)-1)+1));
     fnkd = fnkd +(-1*(Zi(i)*(Ki(i)-1)^2)/(nv(Ki(i)-1)+1)^2);
end
if fnkd ~= 0 
     nv = nv0 - fnk/fnkd;
  else
      nv = nv0 + 0.01;
  end
end
nv
```

This is the error I'm getting: Error in FlashCal (line 74) fnk = fnk + ((Zi(i) * (Ki(i)-1))/(nv(Ki(i)-1)+1));

Where:
 fnk = sigma(i) Zi(Ki-1)/nv(Ki-1)+1 
fnkd = - sigma(i) Zi(Ki-1)^2/(nv(Ki-1)+1)^2

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nv(Ki(i)-1) is not valid. Either you mean nv*(Ki(i)-1) or Ki(i)-1 should evaluate to an integer since you use it to access nv at position (Ki(i)-1). However, it is 2.8, i.e. (3.8-1)